# T/F: If $a \in\operatorname{Span}\{b,c\}$, $b\in\operatorname{Span}\{a,c\}$. All vectors are non-zero.

Tags: vector-spaces

I already know that the answer is false, but I don't understand why.

From what I understand, if $a \in\operatorname{Span}\{b,c\}$, then $a, b,$ and $c$ all on the same plane. Therefore, $b \in \text{Span}\{a,c\}$.

In what situation(s) would the statement be false?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $a = (0, 1)$, $b = (1, 0)$ and $c = (0, 1)$.

---

What worked here is that $a$ and $c$ only span a line, not a full plane.

Comment: a is zero here, but the requirements are that all vectors are non zero.

Comment: @Ascorbyl Yes, thank you. I've fixed it now.

Comment: Ah, thank you! It seems so simple now that I think of it. :P

Answer (score 1):

Let three vectors $v,w,\text{ and } u \in V$. By definition, $\text{span}(v,w) = k_0v + c_0w,$ where $k_0,w_0 \in \mathbb{F}$.

If another vector, say $u \in span(v,w)$, then the vector $u$ can be expressed as the linear combination $k_0v + c_0w$ and therefore, $u$ is a linearly dependent vector in the list $(u,v,w)$.

Suppose that $v \in \text{span}(u,w)$. Since $v$ can be expressed as the combination $k_1u+c_1w$, where $k_1, c_1 \in \mathbb{F}$. It is clear by this notion that $v$ is also linearly dependent vector in the list $(u,v,w)$. If two of the vectors are linearly dependent in a list of three vectors, then $\text{span}(u,v,w) = \text{span }w$.

Since the $\text{span}$ of the three vectors equal to the $\text{span}$ of one, the three vectors span a line segment.

It is false that all vectors are non-zero, because it is possible that the linearly dependent vectors $u = v = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb R^2$, try to find vectors such that the span of $\{a,c\}$ is one-dimensional, but the span of $\{a,b\}$ is two-dimensional.